# IOT Mosquitto mqtt how to test on localhost

Tags: mqtt, iot, mosquitto

I'm just playing around with mosquitto ans mqtt protocol
following the very good video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=WE7GVIFRV7Q

trying to test it on my localhost

in a terminal window I run :

```
mosquitto_sub -t "nodeconf/eu" -v
```

but when I run this snippet:

```
var mqtt    = require('mqtt');
var client  = mqtt.connect();
 client.on('connect', function () {
  client.subscribe('nodeconf/eu');
  client.publish('nodeconf/eu','Hello');
});


client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  // message is Buffer 
  console.log(message.toString());
  client.end();
});
```

I don't see (in my terminal window) any Hello.

What's wrong, please ?

BTW
I'm also looking for good tutorial and guide on the topic thanks.

Comment: Are you saying you don't get the output in the mosquitto_sub window or the nodejs one? If it's the nodejs then you may be attaching the on 'message' listener after the publish has completed.

Comment: I don't get the Hello message in the mosquitto_sub window. Sorry van you give me an example, please ?

Comment: Having now managed to get to a machine to run the code, it looks fine and runs as expected. I assume you have broker running as a service on your machine. I would run it in a terminal in the foreground to check that you can see the clients connecting.

Comment: @Whisher did you find any solution for this? I am just stuck into this cannot see messages in the mosquitto_sub terminal

Comment: @JN_newbie sorry It's been a long time since then I can not remember if I've found a solution or not

Answer (score 4):

You have to add a console.log to your second (the javascript) client to see why it doesn't publishes the Hello properly.

But you can do a typical test with the mosquitto clients:

1) Subscribing to a topic:

`mosquitto_sub -d -h localhost -p 1883 -t "myfirst/test"`

2) Other client publishes a message content to that topic:

`mosquitto_pub -d -h localhost -p 1883 -t "myfirst/test" -m "Hello"`

3) All the subscribed clients to this topic will automatically get the message.